# Relative file paths in PHP header file

Tags: php, header-files, relative-path

I made a php header to prevent editing the same content numerous times on my website, but ran into a problem with filepaths.

I have my header stored inside the same directory as my `CSS` file and index page. So if I want to include the header lets say in `website/products/category/product1.php` but my header is in the website directory the CSS will not get loaded.

I've seen people mention `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/header.php');` to work, since it utilizes relative file path to the server root folder, would this also work inside the HTML when linking?

So if I had `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">` inside my header.php could I do something similar so that my css gets loaded no matter what directory I'm currently in?

Comment: The browser doesn't have direct access to the server's hard disk drive, so it won't even know what to do with file system paths. Why don't you just hard-code the base URL path?

Comment: Never done it before, hence I'm asking what is the best way to achieve it :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use full path when referencing files in HTML:

E.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

Will search for `style.css` under your public root, e.g. `/home/user/www/public`, regardless of which path the HTML itself comes from.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
```

Will look it up under `/home/user/www/public/css`.